# Ordenamiento de una tabla en html

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy haciendo este query insulso:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE vigente=1 ORDER BY fecha DESC";
```

fecha es un campo DATETIME. Teóricamente tiene que ordenar el resultado de mas reciente al mas antiguo... pues bien, en PHPMyAdmin funciona perfecto... luego cuando lo coloco en la tabla hace lo que se le antoja !!!... 
Lo extraño es que por ejemplo probe

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE vigente=1 ORDER BY id DESC";
```

no mostrando el campo id en la tabla. En PHPMyAdmin también funciona perfecto, pero como no muestro el campo id en la tabla pensé "por ahí es medio mañoso y si no esta el campo por ahí ignora el ordenamiento" (uno a esta altura ya no sabe qué sandeces pensar) pues bien, para probar agregue el campo id en la tabla y pasó exactamente lo mismo... hace lo que se le canta en gana... 
Quiero aclarar que en la tabla coloco: titulo, resumen, fecha (de publicación), nada mas
El resultado de ese query lo almaceno en

```
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

y más abajo en el "tbody" hago

```
<?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
```

el problema tendría que estar en alguna de esas partes... ya que si el query esta bien, cargo bien el resultado del query... entonces...

Comment: Todas esas partes individualmente parecen estar bien, ¿podrías ponerlas en contexto dentro de tu código para que podamos ver si pasa algo? También si es posible, añade un pequeño ejemplo de los datos contenidos en tu tabla y su estructura/diseño sql

Comment: Lo que no sabes es si estas obteniendo correctamente los datos o montando bien el HTML. Haz un *var_dump()* de lo que te devuelve tu consulta para aclararte.